# Displaying users previous page in iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to display a users previously visited page in an iFrame.

For example: if someone visited example.com, and then visited mysite.com then an iframe on my page would display an iframe with example.com in it.

I have the following code:

index.html

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome to mysite!</h1>
        <h3>Click the button to see a site you have previously visited</h3>
        <button id="button" onclick="magic()">Magic</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="results"></div>

    <iframe id="myIFrame" height="80%" width="100%" class="netframe" src="http://www.cnn.com/"></iframe>
</body>
```

index.js

```
function magic (){

    $("#button").click(function(event){            
        $("#myIFrame").attr('src', window.history.back());
    });

}
```

Now, I am trying to use the window.history.back() method, but nothing shows up when I try doing this. When i click the button, the iframe does not display the previous page. Is this something that is possible to do?

EDIT: 
I would like this to work in such a way that a user is first at example.com and then they TYPE in mysite.com to reach my site. The navigation from example.com to mysite.com is not through links on example.com

Answer (score 2):

use `document.referrer` to get previous page url and then add it to src of iframe.

`$("#ifram_id").attr("src",document.referrer);`

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: won't this only work if the user clicks on a link of my site from the site they are currently looking at? @Shubham

Comment: Id like it so that is not the case. I want it so that if a user goes from one site to my site by typing my site in the browser. Not by clicking links.  @Shubham

Answer (score 0):

Your JS function is correct but need to change from

```
`$("#myIFrame").attr('src', window.history.back());`
```

to change

```
`$("#myIFrame").attr('src', window.history.back(0));`
```

Comment: This does not work not either. Do you think that it has anything to do with me testing it as a local file? It shouldn't right? @Aman

Comment: use this one:  <a href = "javascript:history.back()">Back to previous page</a>

Comment: Reffer this link : [Link Here](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/04/16/getting-the-url-of-an-iframes-parent/)

Comment: See that code works from within the HTML, but I would like it to work when I click the button. How would I do that from the javascript side?@Aman